# Brownian motion and Running Maximum

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Take B$_t$ as a standard Brownian motion such that B$_0$ = 0. And M$_t$ is the corresponding running maximum. i.e. M$_t$ = max$_{0\leq s \leq t}$ B$_s$.  My goal is to compute:

(i) Quadratic Variation of  M$_t$ on interval [0,T]

The quadratic variation of B$_t$ over [0,T] is T, but how can we compute that for running maximum

M$_t$?

(ii) The probability density function of M$_t$

I calculate it by using the joint density function of M$_t$ and 
B$_t$, which is

f$_{M(t),B(t)}$(m,w) = $\frac{2(2m-w)}{t\sqrt{2 \pi t}}$e$^{-\frac{(2m-w)^2}{2t}}$. It implies that f$_{M_t}$(m) = $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ f$_{M(t),B(t)}$(m,w) dw, but what I get is zero after some calculation. A bit weird. Any comments?

Comment: Concerning the quadratic variation: $t\mapsto M_t$ is non-decreasing, so of finite (first order) variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot that $M_t \geq B_t$. The joint density you have obtained is only for $m \geq w$ so the integral for computing $f_{M_t}(m)$ is from $-\infty$ to $m$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! By the way, how can we compute the quadratic variation of M_t? It seems like there is no fact about the distribution of increments of running maximum.